# Sampling timestamped data every 2 minutes in R

Tags: r

I have some lat/long data which is being collected every 10 seconds when a GPS unit is on.  These coordinates are obviously timestamped.  This is far too much data for my purposes (30K plus observations), so I want to be left with a dataframe with data every 2 minutes instead.  How would I do this in R?

I have created an example dataframe below.  The date and time are intergrated into one column, and it's this column by which I would hope to sample my data.

```
a <-c(1:21)
D <- c("2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14")
Time <- c("18:40:37", "18:40:48", "18:40:58", "18:41:08","18:41:18","18:41:28","18:41:38","18:41:48","18:41:58","18:42:08","18:42:18","18:42:28","18:42:38","18:42:48","18:42:58","18:43:08","18:43:18","18:42:28", "18:44:18", "18:44:28", "18:44:28")
df1 <- data.frame(a, D, Time)

df1 <- within(df1, { timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(D, Time)), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })
```

The units can be switched on and off throughout the day, so there may not be any consistency with which seconds are being recorded.

What is the best way of doing this in R?

Many thanks,
Katie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be something like this:

```
df1[seq(to=nrow(df1), by=12),]
```

It means “take every 12th row, starting at the first”. It might be slightly suboptimal in cases where the unit was switched off, but unless that happens very often and in very rapid succession, it shouldn't matter too much.

My first suggestion here was the following:

```
df1[(1:floor(nrow(df1)/12))*12,]
```

It does pretty much the same, but starts at row 12 instead of row 1. `1:n` is a range of integers from `1` to `n`. So in this case I build a range of all the integers up to the largest integer no larger than the number of rows divided by 12. I then multiply all these numbers by 12. This version is less clear than the above, but was the first thing that came to my mind and might be useful to know nevertheless.

Comment: Many thanks @ MvG - Can I ask what the '1' does in your example? When I apply your code to my complete dataset, R is not picking out the 12th value.  I have 1/12 of the values in my revised dataset but many of the first lot of values which I can easily identify go up in 2 (i.e. 18:40:48, 18:41:08).  I am just wondering what has gone wrong?

Comment: @KT_1, I had a mistake in my original version: wrote `2` instead of `12`. Updated my answer and also included a version which is easier to understand.